# RuntimeException while recording video [Device specific]

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to record video from camera everything is working fine but in **Samsung SM-C7010** it showing an error message **start failed**.

Here is what I'm using.

```
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    /*CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_720P);
    mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(profile.videoFrameRate/6.0f);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);*/
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(String.valueOf(camMediaFile));
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(5000);
    mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(profile.videoFrameRate/6.0f);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(10);

    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(videoOrientation);

   // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.getHolder().getSurface());


    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder

    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    mMediaRecorder.start();
```

Everything works fine when I remove these two lines

```
   mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(profile.videoFrameRate/6.0f);
   mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(10);
```

I think the problem is in these two lines but don't know what the problem is.

**Update (Log file)**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
   at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(MediaRecorder.java)
   at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:1170)
   at org.octabyte.zeem.Camera.CameraHandler.startGifRecording(CameraHandler.java:484)
   at org.octabyte.zeem.Camera.camfrags.Initializer$3.clicked(Initializer.java:230)
   at org.octabyte.zeem.Camera.camutil.CameraListener.onClick(CameraListener.java:67)
   at org.octabyte.zeem.Camera.helper.OnSwipeTouchListener$GestureListener.onSingleTapUp(OnSwipeTouchListener.java:43)
   at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:651)
   at org.octabyte.zeem.Camera.helper.OnSwipeTouchListener.onTouch(OnSwipeTouchListener.java:27)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10775)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2886)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:605)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1895)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3241)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:567)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:11008)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5155)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5007)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4684)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4741)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7024)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6985)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7202)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: please add full error log

Comment: please check the update

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859458/how-to-use-setcamera-mediarecorder

Comment: What I checked there. It's total different from this question I already setup everything correctly. Only problem is in specifc mobile model. I also mention the lines where the problem is but don't know what the exact problem and how to solve

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(20);
  mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
```

Comment: why you set the value for both 20 ?